# Using constraint in table of teacher and students

Tags: sql

For example, I have 3 tables: teachers, students and persons.

Teachers with teacher_id and person_id,

Students with student_id and person_id,

Persons with person_id and some information about him.

How should I use constraint to avoid situation, when the same person is teacher and student. I know how to use constraint in simple ways, like limiting dates or other integer values. But here I have no idea how to connect and constraint them.

Comment: @jarlh that's not the point, I can't understand the concept

Comment: I don't see any relational mapping problem. Basically the same foreign key person_id appears in two different tables (i.e.: students and teachers) if a person is both one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `SELECT` all `persons`, but the `students` who are `teachers`, you can put that in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM persons p
INNER JOIN student_id s
   ON s.person_id = p.person_id
INNER JOIN teacher_id t
   ON t.person_id = p.person_id
WHERE student_id != teacher_id
```

---

Update

Use the WHERE clause in a CASE statement while creating your index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_person ON index_table(
  CASE WHEN student_id != teacher_id
       THEN person_id
       ELSE NULL
  END
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is not about selecting from table. I wanted to create the database with setting I described in question.